# Preprocessor/stack Java Assignment

Tags: java, stack, preprocessor

Hey everyone I need assistance with my java assignment, this is the assignment:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU2dj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmCxI.png

And I have attached my code as well. Can someone Help me out,
I do not know why I am getting errors. The code is not compiling as well. Please let me know what I can do, thank you:) !

```
package APackage;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;



public class MyPreprocessor

{

//MAIN METHOD

          public static void main (String [] args)

    {

       

//FileReader AND BuffeRedreader TO READ FROM FILE


          FileReader fk = new FileReader("tet.txt");

          BufferedReader bk = new BufferedReader(fk);

          Preprocessor p;

          String preLine;

//READING FROM FILE

          while((preLine=br.readLine(bk))!=null)

          {

//DISPLAY THE STRING AS WELL AS CHECK ITS BALANCED DELIMITERS

              System.out.println("Line is: "+preLine +" is Balanced?"+balance_Chek(preLine));

          }

    }

}
```

This is the second required class called Preprocessor

```
package APackage;


import java.util.Stack;

import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

class Preprocessor

{

     public static boolean balance_Chek(String inStr12)

    {

        Stack<Character> s_st1 = new Stack<Character>();

        for(int k1 = 0; k1 < inStr12.length(); k1++)

        {

                   char let = inStr12.charAt(k1);

                   if(let == '[' || let == '{' || let == '('||let=='/')

                   {

                        switch(let)

                        {

                    // FORSQUARE BRACKET

                                  case '[':

                                      s_st1.push(let);

                                      break;

                    // FOR CURLY BRACE

                                  case '{':

                                      s_st1.push(let);

                                      break;

                    // FOR BRACKETS

                                  case '(':

                                      s_st1.push(let);;

                                      break;

                //FOR COMMANDS

                        case '/':

                             char t=inStr12.charAt(k1+1);

                             if(t=='*')

                             s_st1.push(let);

                  

                             break;

                                  default:

                                  break;

                        }

                   }

                   else if(let == ']' || let == '}' || let == ')'||let=='*')

                   {

                        if(s_st1.empty())

                                  return false;

                        switch(let)

                        {

// FORSQUARE BRACKET

                                  case ']':

                                      if (s_st1.pop() != '[')

                                      return false;

                                      break;

// FOR CURLY BRACE

                                  case '}':

                                      if (s_st1.pop() != '{')

                                           return false;

                                      break;

                    // FOR BRACKETS

                                  case ')':

                                      if (s_st1.pop() != '(')

                                      return false;

                                      break;

                //FOR COMMANDS

                        case '*':

                             if(inStr12.charAt(k1+1)=='/')

                                      if (s_st1.pop() != '/')

                                      return false;

                                      break;

                                  default:

                                      break;

                        }

                   }

        }

        if(s_st1.empty())//CHECK STACK IS EMPTY

                   return true;

        return false;

    }//EMD METHOD

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What's the error you're getting when you try to compile?

Comment: Tighten your code up so it's less painful to read.  It seems when you pasted it in here every carriage return became two.  Also, why do you have a test, then a switch on the same value?  Just switch there, and include a default if you want to do something for all values other than the ones you check for.